# create a Timestamp object in angularfire app

Tags: angular, firebase, timestamp, angularfire2

First tried

```
import { Timestamp } from '@firebase/firestore-types';
```

and then how to create a Timestamp object?

```
var now: Timestamp = ???

var now: Timestamp = Timestamp.now() //Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@firebase/firestore-types'
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import { Timestamp } from '@firebase/firestore-types';
```

Here Timestamp is just a type, if you want to get the current time just use

```
var now = new Date(;
```

Answer (score 2):

JS Date objects do get saved as timestamps in Firestore/firebase:

```
ref.update({ updatedAt: new Date() })
// results in timestamp in Firestore
```

Comment: This is the actual answer

Answer (score 2):

Using **serverTimestamp()** method to update the Timestamp object

```
import {serverTimestamp } from 'firebase/firestore';

ref.update({ updatedAt: serverTimestamp() })
// results in timestamp in Firestore
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Timestamp from firestore-types. The one you can use is available in firestore.

Use
`import { Timestamp } from "@firebase/firestore";`

instead of
`import { Timestamp } from "@firebase/firestore-types";`

Then you can use: `Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());`